# Knockout computed observable object individual bindings not refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

So I have this complicated app now and one part it dynamically creates a table, with an unknown amount of headers. To accomplish this I just treat the JavaScript object as a dictionary and if the key doesn't exist add it:

```
function getHeaders (objs) {
    var headers = {};

    $.each(objs, function(i, el) {
        for (var key in el) {
            if (headers[key] === undefined)
                headers[key]=key;
        }
    });

    return headers;
}
```

So this will creat a list of headers that will contain the max amount of headers. So for instance if an object only contained headers `header 1` and `header 2`, but the second object had all those headers and one more `header 3`, then the `headers` object created will have `header 1-3`.

This all works nicely. But I want a `computed` to show a summary of each value under the header, so I do this:

```
self.totals = ko.computed(function () {
    var vals = {keys:[]};
    $.each(self.itemList(), function (i, el) {
        for (var key in el){
            if (el[key] instanceof nutCalcModel){
                if (vals[key] === undefined) vals[key] = 0;
                    vals[key] += el[key].total;

                    vals.keys.push(key);
                }
            }
    });

    console.log(vals);

    return vals;
});
```

and this works great, gives the totals for each header. My bindings look like this (skeleton though):

```
<div class="well" data-bind="foreach: totals().keys">
    <div><b data-bind="text: $data"></b>:&nbsp;<span data-bind="text: $parent.totals()[$data]"></span></div>
</div>
```

Now these work a treat when the first item is added to the table (`ko.observableArray()`). But when subsequent items are added, the HTML bindings are added thus showing duplicate headers and values, rather than re-writing the entire lot. So the output after two items added would be:

```
Header 1: value
Header 2: value
Header 3: value
Header 1: value
Header 2: value
Header 3: value
```

Where the second set of `Header 1-3` show the new updated values.

Do I have to wrap the HTML in another binding or something? I'm not sure where to go with this.

I would do a fiddle but its very complicated and would take me forever.

Comment: Helping you would be a lot easier if you would take the time to create a fiddle (it's possible that you would even find the issue yourself, while creating the fiddle). So please create a fiddle. That being said, I'm guessing the problem is the computation of the `totals` computed observable. You do `vals.keys.push(key);` (line 9 in the second code sample) even if the key already exists in the `vals.keys` array, so you'll end up with duplicates in the keys array.

Comment: Yeah, I will get around to it this afternoon hopefully. I think that might be the answer in all honesty, I will have to try that.

Comment: Hahahaha, I bet you didnt even know you just fixed the issue :) I just test it and it works, I will post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as per Robert Westerlund comment on the OP, he made the point that I would be adding duplicate keys. So I modified the code and it worked, perfectly :)

Here is said code:

```
self.totals = ko.computed(function () {
    var vals = {keys:[]};
    $.each(self.itemList(), function (i, el) {
        for (var key in el){
            if (el[key] instanceof nutCalcModel){
                if (vals[key] === undefined) vals[key] = 0;
                vals[key] += el[key].total;

                if (vals.keys.indexOf(key) === -1)
                    vals.keys.push(key);
            }
        }
    });

    console.log(vals);

    return vals;
});
```

So the line `if (vals.keys.indexOf(key) === -1)` checks whether the item doesn't exist, if so add it.